# Greater than or identical to?

Tags: language-design, comparison, operators

While browsing my code in a weakly-typed language I was seeing that I've trained myself to use identity (`===`) where logical. Then I came across a greater (or less) than or equal to (`>=`), and it made me wonder... why is there no "greater than or identical to"? I suppose it would be `>==`. For example...

```
5 == 5    // true
5 === 5   // true
5.5 >= 5  // true
5.5 >== 5 // false
6 >= 5    // true
6 >== 5   // true
```

Basically, I would throw a false if it was of a different type. For example, if I want to check if $x is greater than $y, but I want them both to be integers (or floats, but no mixing), then wouldn't it make sense to have a single call that can do all that, rather than having to check separately to see if they were the same type?

A quick google indicated that this may not exist in any language; why not? Is it just not as useful as I might think it is? :)

Comment: I'm confused about why `5.5 >== 5` is false, but I never used the identity operator much back when I did PHP...

Comment: @Frustrated: I think because 5.5 is floating point type and 5 is an integer type, and the identity operator returns false if two values are different types.

Comment: Right. It's not so much "are these greater than or identical", but rather, "is this greater than or equal to that, and of the same type?"

Comment: I see someone added a PHP tag; I disagree, as this is kind of language agnostic, as I don't see any weakly-typed language using this construction, and I was curious as to why not.

Comment: @Matt: That sort of makes sense... but that means that the hypothetical `>==` is doing two things: testing that the two operands and if they are, compare values of them. That is confusing and I don't like it. Would `>==` only be applicable to numeric operands? What if I tried `$shoppingcart >== $user_acct_info`? Would that even make sense? I think that `$shoppingcart === $user_acct_info` *might* make sense (I think it would test if the two are of the same type), but `>==`? ... I dunno man...

Comment: Isn't `===` doing two things, though? It tests that the two operands are identical and, if they are, compares the values.

Comment: @Andrew - I agree, so I replaced the PHP tag with language-design. Please consider removing the language-specific parts of the the post from your question to avoid such confusion.

Comment: @Andrew: You're the one who uses it; are you not certain?

Comment: @Frustrated, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @Andrew: You asked a question: "Isn't === doing two things, though?". I responded by saying that you posted this question (and you seemed to understand `===` does) and then you post a comment sounding very unsure about what `===` does. Maybe you intended that comment to sound different...?

Comment: you said, "It seems that the hypothetical `>==` is doing two things... that is confusing and I don't like it." But the existing `===` does two things as well, in fact the same two things, does it not? Do you not like it either? :)

Comment: @Andrew: No. I do not like either of these operators. :)

Comment: @Andrew: `===` does one thing - tests if two things are identical *including their types*. Your proposed `>==` tests if the types are identical and if so compares them. If this is a valid operation, then so is "test if they are the same type and if so, check if one is strictly greater than the other", and how would you notate that?

Comment: The 5.5 >== 5 thing being false is seriously counterintuitive, and that's why I'd strongly recommend against that.  Identity or equality operators are reasonable, in that they do one conceptual thing.  If I understand properly, `===` returns true if things are of the same type and are equal, or if they're the same thing, or something like that, and that's one conceptual thing even if it's two separate operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it does seem like this is an inadequacy in a language that uses `===` (examples are in JavaScript):

```
5 == "5" // true
5 === "5" // false
5 >= "5" // true
```

However, two things:

1. In PHP, there are few if any instances in which a `string` number isn't converted automatically into a number type. (See my [answer about casting in PHP](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/type-casting-variables-in-php-is-there-a-practical-example/24493#24493))
2. Using `===` with numbers isn't really that useful - after all, implicit conversion is a *feature* of weak typing that is usually desirable.  The **much** more common usage is making sure you getting the right comparison with all the "**falsey**" values -- `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `""`.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer. I personally use explicit typecasting only as a method for sanitizing for database input; if I know that the field expects an int, I can simply cast it to int rather than go through the escaping and quoting business. And yes, I try to avoid using === for numbers because sometimes a query or form might have inserted a numeric string into the process. Or, sometimes when I'm passing it to something expecting a boolean. But as you said, typecasting "down".

Answer (score 4):

I think that such an operator would be too confusing by mixing the concepts of logical ordering and object identity.  A proper implementation of >= and <= should account for this scenario anyway.  Maybe I'm wrong, it's been a while since I've used PHP.